# Ubuntu 22.04lts Settings Display Unknown display options

Tags: multiple-monitors

Installed Ubuntu 22.04lts on a mini computer.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46d2

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

I'm not a ubuntu guru. I looked everywhere on the net. Only answers I see are for NVIDIA drivers not Intel.
When I go in Settings Display I got: unknown display and only the 1920 x 1080 resolution.
System is on dual monitor (two Acer) via HDMI.
Got the same display on both monitors.
Cannot have the choice of Joint Monitors or Mirror Monitors.
This mini computer comes with Windows 11 loaded and both monitors work fine under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Went to Intel site for GPU installation process for Ubuntu.
I was on 22.04 lts with kernel 5.15.
I have the 12th generation graphic chips and they ask to add 5.19 kernel with which I didn't have much success (unstable monitors).
I decided to start a fresh installation with Ubuntu 22.04.3 lts and finally my monitors are detected and everything went back to normal.